# Python/Oracle/cx_Oracle date behavior with year=0 issues

Tags: python, oracle, postgresql, psycopg2, cx-oracle

I'm currently working on some ETL code to incrementally load data from a source Oracle system to a Postgresql analysis environment with Python as the glue.

I am leveraging cx_Oracle as the driver to pull the Oracle data, but I am running into some strange issues with Oracle Date and Python datetime and year 0.

As far as I understand, neither Oracle nor Python support year 0. I've isolated a particular row and field with an offending Date:

```
SELECT
  CAR_RENTAL_DATE,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAR_RENTAL_DATE)
FROM
  TRXNS_ALL
WHERE
  TRX_ID = 50079327
```

Here are the results from the sqlplus CLI:

```
CAR_RENTA EXTRACT(YEARFROMCAR_RENTAL_DATE)
--------- --------------------------------
30-JUN-00                0
```

According to this post, it is actually possible to create an Oracle Date with year 0, but its not officially supported in the docs: http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2008/10/year-zero.html

The issue I am having is the Python representation that cx_Oracle is returning to me:

```
cur.execute('select CAR_RENTAL_DATE, extract(year from CAR_RENTAL_DATE) FROM TRXNS_ALL where TRX_ID = 50079327')
res = cur.fetchone()
print repr(res[0]), type(res[0])
```

Which results in the following:

```
datetime.datetime(0, 6, 30, 0, 0) <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Strangely (but expectedly), creating the same Python datetime gives me an error:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(0, 6, 30, 0, 0)

ValueError: year is out of range
```

When I attempt to insert this datetime to a Postgresql timestamp field with psycopg2, the insertion fails, as expected.

What is really going on here? How do Oracle and Python both support year 0 despite their documentation?

What is a good way to handle this aside from iterating over every tuple value returned by cx_Oracle to detect and handle year=0?

Comment: As to why cx_Oracle is able to create the funky datetime: [it uses the C-API](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_oracle/src/1a6c77089c453202cd687de7a5c8cb06aca4c35d/Transforms.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Transforms.c-26).

Comment: What do you get if you `SELECT DUMP( CAR_RENTAL_DATE ) FROM TRXNS_ALL WHERE TRX_ID = 50079327`?

Comment: @IljaEverilä that makes sense

Comment: @IljaEverilä You can create the date using pure SQL: `SELECT DATE '0000-06-30' FROM DUAL`.

Comment: @MT0 this is the output `Typ=12 Len=7: 100,100,6,30,1,1,1`

Comment: @MT0 meant why cx_Oracle is able to create the 0 year *python* datetime object from the Oracle datetime. Normally you'd get an exception.

Comment: Extract the date from Oracle as a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`