# sqlalchemy can't read null dates from sqlite3 (0000-00-00): ValueError: year is out of range

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I try to query a database containing dates such as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` with `sqlachemy`, I get `ValueError: year is out of range`.

Here's the db dump:

[image]

Here's the stacktrace:

```
File "/home/rob/.virtualenvs/calif/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py" in items
  163.         return [(key, self[key]) for key in self.keys()]

File "/home/rob/.virtualenvs/calif/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py" in <listcomp>
  163.         return [(key, self[key]) for key in self.keys()]

File "/home/rob/.virtualenvs/calif/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py" in __getitem__
  90.                 return processor(self._row[index])

File "/home/rob/.virtualenvs/calif/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/processors.py" in process
  48.                 return type_(*list(map(int, m.groups(0))))

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: year is out of range
```

Is this normal ? Can sqlalchemy read dates like that ? Is this a python limitation ? Is there a workaround to keep the date as-is (not converting to None) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer via `inklesspen` on IRC: [Python datetime representation has **minimum year** and it's **1**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.MINYEAR)

Comment: Interestingly enough you [sort of can create `datetime` objects with year 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712411/python-oracle-cx-oracle-date-behavior-with-year-0-issues), though you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass the problem by using sqlalchemy.text

```
from sqlalchemy import text

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("select * from table"))
    ....
```