# Unable to get null in datetime column Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

I have a table ServerHistory with multiple varchar and datetime fields in a SybaseASE database and I am using pyodbc library to connect to the database from my Python codebase.

The table allows for null datetime and has a few records where updDate is null but when I execute a sql from Python to read such records, I never get null in the updDate field.

Instead it picks up the value of previous datetime field liveDate and fills it as updDate. If I just select updDate, it gives me a ValueError "year 0/any no. is out of range".

connection=pyodbc.connect('connection_str')
results=connection.execute("select updDate from ServerHistory where server=\'srvr1\'").fetchone()

ValueError: year 31728 is out of range

I believe the error maybe happening because Python does not allow times below min year of 1 as per [sqlalchemy can't read null dates from sqlite3 (0000-00-00): ValueError: year is out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118266/sqlalchemy-cant-read-null-dates-from-sqlite3-0000-00-00-valueerror-year-is)

Nevertheless, I still don't understand how to resolve my issue to get null as the datetime when I execute the query.

Comment: Please share what you have tried (code). Read the help page on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: You might try using a pyodbc [Output Converter function](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function) to capture the raw bytes and return `None` if the bytes correspond to a date/time that Python's `datetime` can't handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hack-Ish:**

Use `coalesce(updDate ,  date('0001/01/01')` where you `select updDate, .. from ...` and treat any such `updDate` as `None` when you use the data gathered from pyodbc.